# Edit Button Click data pass into the form using React Laravel

Tags: reactjs

i am a beginner of React.I am creating a simple crud using react and laravel.i can successfully add the records and able to view the records  to the table.but i need to update the record. i having a problem is when i click edit button selected row record need to be pass into the form.but i tried it.but it doesn't work.what i tried so far i attached below.can you solve this problem i need to pass the record in to form.

**Table Design successfully view the records**

```
<table class="table table-dark" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Employee Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee Mobile</th>
      
      <th scope="col">Option</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
       {users.map(function fn(item)
       {
            return(
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">{item.id} </th>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.address}</td>
                <td>{item.mobile}</td> 
              
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"  onClick={editEmployee(users)}>Edit</button>    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" >Delete </button>
                </td>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
            );
            })}
            </table>
                </div>
            );
        }
```

but when i click the edit button records not pass into the edit form. i checked throw the console i got the error**.Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.**

Form design and Variable

```
function EmployeeLoad()
{
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");


const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>
{
  Load();
},[])

  async function editEmployee(users)
  {
   console.log(users.name); 

  }


 
  async function  Load()
  {
     const result = await axios.get(
         "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees");
         setUsers(result.data);
         console.log(result.data);
  }
 


    async function  handleClick(event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/save",
      {
          name: name,
          address: address,
          mobile: mobile
      }
      );
      alert("Employee Registation success");
    }


  return (
    <div>
       <h1>Employee Details</h1>
       <div class="container mt-4" >
          <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>employeeName</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeName"
                onChange={(event) =>
                  {
                    setName(event.target.value);      
                  }}
                />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>employeeAddress</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeAddress" 
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    {
                      setAddress(event.target.value);      
                    }}

                />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mobile</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeMobile" 
                
                onChange={(event) =>
                  {
                    setMobile(event.target.value);      
                  }}
                
                
                
                />
              </div>

              <button   class="btn btn-primary mt-4"  onClick={handleClick}  >Register</button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: Change `onClick={editEmployee(users)}` to `onClick={() => editEmployee(users)}`.

Comment: i changed it  like this onClick={() => editEmployee(users)}    but when i click the edit button now result display as undefined